# New to MVC - how do I create a View that has links to Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

This is surely a basic question, but I'm new enough to MVC (and ASP.NET) I don't even know how to ask the question without explaining it...

I want to have one tab on the master page that loads a View with links to other views.  The purpose is to create one "Admin" view that contains links (action links?) to the various Controllers/Actions/View to maintain the master tables for my database.  All these would be secured with an Authorize filter.

So, the main tab would say Admin. That should load a View with Action Links to the Controller/View for TableA, TableB, etc.  Clicking on one of these links should then take me to the View where I can do CRUD operations on that particular table. I have these built already, but am using the Shared/Site.Master view to get to each table, creating a separate tab for each table -- not good.

I envision a vertical list of clickable table names.

Is this clear enough?  I am not even sure of the terminology I need to use here...

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, recommend you reading up on the NerdDinner tutorial asap, it covers all of the basics.

What it sounds like you will want is an AdminController.  the index action of that will return a view.  the View file of that is where you'll place your actionlinks.

The master page, would then just call

```
@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "index", "admin");
```

and that should generate the link you're looking for, assuming you havne't mucked w/ routing yet.

Comment: I highly recommend T4MVC for referencing stuff. It allows you to express routes and links to actions or views in a strongly typed way, which makes refactoring much easier.

Comment: T4MVC overall is a win for sure, but it's a bit quirky at times. The tactic in this blog post helps: http://devtalk.dk/2010/03/11/How+To+Run+T4MVC+On+Build.aspx

Comment: @Morten: Totally agree, T4MVC is how links should have been done in the core framework, it's kind of a shame that it's an IDE plugin.

Comment: I have been through the NerdDinner tutorial several times, that's about all I know at the moment. It may be simpler than what I think it will be to accomplish, I just don't "grok" it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the T4MVC suggestion, I will follow up with that.

Comment: I would mark this as the answer, but I already knew how to do what you stated. What I need is how to create the Index View for the AdminController -- what you referred to as "place your actionlinks". I'm hoping the T4MVC links will give me what I need for that...

Comment: ? You mean like, right click on the Index action and select Add View?

Comment: No, I really was just looking for the syntax.  And, it really is easier than I imagined it might be, I just suck at HTML...  :(

Comment: This is probably the answer most people would be looking for, so I marked it as the correct one. Between NerdDinner, T4MVC and a web page on HTML syntax I was able to get it to work very nicely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea for strongly typed action links, based on a [SharpArch](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Web/Areas/LinkForAreasExtensions.cs) extension method.

```
public IHtmlString ActionLink<T>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Action<T>> action, string linkText) where T : Controller
{
  var methodCall = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
  if (methodCall == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Action must be a method call", "action");

  var actionName = methodCall.Method.Name;
  var controllerName = GetControllerName(typeof(T));

  return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
}

public static string GetControllerName(Type controllerType)
{
  return controllerType.Name.Substring(0, controllerType.Name.Length - "Controller".Length);
}
```

Then you could use this way:

```
@Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c => c.Index(), "My Home Index")
```

Please be aware it's just an idea, not tested yet.

Hope this helps.